# Permission denied when connect to Remote Docker

Tags: docker, ssh, permission-denied

What I did to setup:

- I can `ssh` to the remote machine without password.
- I already added user to docker group `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}`, and I can run `docker run hello-word` without sudo on both host and local machine.
- I already did `ssh-add` on my local machine. `ssh-add -l` shows `2048 SHA256:asdasdas ... (RSA)`.
- I already tried restarting docker `sudo service docker start`.

But when I run the command:

```sh
docker -H ssh://host_user@host_ip:host_port ps
```

I still get the permission error:

```
error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.24/containers/json": fork/exec /usr/bin/ssh: permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, so it turns out that because I install Docker with Snap.
Uninstall `sudo snap remove docker`, and then install it again with

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

solve the problem.

Comment: I suggest using these tutorials to install Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/